# How Dynamically Generate Div tag inside of Div tag

Tags: javascript, php

How dynamically Generate Below Code....

```
<div class="test"><input type="text" id="test01">
  <div class="Here"></div>
</div>
```

text box Id should be changed when add new text box. I tried with below code and last div tag(class="here") unable to add.

```js
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var element2 = document.createElement("input");
   element2.type = "text";
                        element2.className="form-control";
                        element2.title="Item-name";
                        element2.id='item-name'+rowCount+'';
   element2.name = "item-name[]";
   cell2.appendChild(element2);
```

Comment: `<div class=test>` is missing quotes, just sayin...

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged jQuery on this question? You aren't using it at all

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the innerHTML property too.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.add("test");
div.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text" id="test01" />
    <div class="here"></div>
`;
```